# Toolbar menu item working fine on emulators but not on real device

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, android-toolbar

I'm trying to run a simple app with toolbar that have 2 menu items ..
these menu items is shown and visible on any kind of emulators .
the problem is that when I try to run the app on a real device like Samsung M20
these 2 items is not visible anymore.
another note is that even when they are not visible on the real device > when I click on the toolbar corner > it shows me the search hint and keybord is open to start searching!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item android:id="@+id/search"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_search_white_24dp"
    android:title="@string/search"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"/>

<item android:id="@+id/cart"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_shopping_cart_white_24dp"
    android:title="@string/cart"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:actionLayout="@layout/cart_menu_item"
    app:actionLayout="@layout/cart_menu_item"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"/>
</menu>
```

any ideas !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by removing the ic_search_white_24dp picture from the mipmap-anydpi-v26 folder... but still not understanding why it may make the item menu showing a blank icon.

Answer (score 0):

inside your both show as action try this:

```
android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
```

Comment: Thank you Mr. Patel for your answer , I try what you just suggest and it shows both the icons on the emulators and only the search icon on the device ... any other suggestions !

Comment: I need the cart icon to be shown also on the device ,,, why it goes invisible?